# Cannot display item in combobox from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I've this combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="notification_mode" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationMode}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
```

in my model I've created a class that add also the value to comboboxitem:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

so in my viewmodel I've created an observableCollection that store all the items:

```
private ObservableCollection<Models.ComboboxItem> _notificationMode = new ObservableCollection<Models.ComboboxItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<Models.ComboboxItem> NotificationMode
    {
        get
        {
            return _notificationMode;
        }
        set
        {
            Models.ComboboxItem item = new Models.ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "Con sonoro";
            item.Value = 0;
            _notificationMode.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

The problem's that in the combobox item isn't displayed nothing. Why happen this?

Comment: I think you might need to implement a NotifyProperty changed event on your collection to notify the designer that an item has been added to the colleciton, otherwise, it will always display the empty collection

Comment: @Marc already tried with OnPropertyChanged.. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard Property declaration

```
public ObservableCollection<Models.ComboboxItem> NotificationMode
{
    get
    {
        return _notificationMode;
    }
    set
    {
        _notificationMode = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NotificationMode");
    }
}
```

You can initialize the above defined property in the ViewModel **constructor**

```
 public YourViewModel()
{
        Models.ComboboxItem item = new Models.ComboboxItem();
        item.Text = "Con sonoro";
        item.Value = 0;
        _notificationMode.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that NotificationMode is never invoked